What if a halal crypto project advertises gambling?
What if a halal crypto project advertises gambling?
I invested in a crypto project called Solidus AI which appeared to be a halal project based on its offering of decentralized physical infrastructure, which is similar to other larger projects that have been deemed halal. The company is establishing a high-performance data center in Europe to address the growing demand for AI services and computational power in the region. The core focus of Solidus AI is on renting out computing power.
However, Solidus AI-Tech, the platform behind Solidus AI, features a launchpad where they introduce other cryptocurrencies and use their website as an advertising space to generate funds for the team. Recently, they promoted a gambling crypto project, raising concerns about the overall halal status of Solidus AI due to its association with gambling.
I want to know whether I need to sell my holdings now or not. I'm currently making a loss and if I have to sell them, I can sell the first one when I'm back at breakeven.

It makes a difference if you invested in the company, or in some crypto-currency they created. I would advise to do neither of that, not based on Islam but on instinct and general mistrust for those companies.
